# How to programmatically replace ^13 with ^p using Word Javascript API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The question can also be "How to programmatically insert ^p using Word Javascript API" as I can locate those ^13 and delete them by range.delete(). But before the deletes, I need to add ^p.

Comment: You need to edit your original question instead of creating a question that alludes mysteriously to some earlier question.

Comment: I got it. I did encounter some issues during the development of a Word add-in. Thanks for pointing it out to me.